Internal date disabling logic in DatePicker, RangePicker antd
Hi could you please help me?
I use RangePicker form antd library
The component have internal logic of disabling date.
For example if we chose startDate the dates that less than start start become disabled
You can try in here.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/range-picker-ant-design-demo-forked-l2fvld?file=%2Findex.js
Is it possible to turn off this internal logic?
I tryed set field:
disabledDate={() => false} and few other options but it is not working.

This behaviour of Antd Range Picker is perfectly fine. We should understand the behaviour of this Range Picker properly. I used Antd components for 18 months in my current organisation.
There are two sections in this Range Picker, i.e, Start Date and End Date. Refer attached image.

When user selects Start Date, Antd Range Picker auto focuses on End Date. Blue underline below End Date section in an image shows focused section in the Range Picker. Once start date is selected and focus is on end date section, user is suppose to pick the end date. As per focus, the user will be selecting an end date, the dates before start date should be disabled as end date can't be smaller that start date. When you again clicks on Start Date section, the dates before selected dates will be enabled. This is perfect behaviour.
In your case, the Range Picker is auto focusing on End Date section after selecting Start Date. But you may be thinking that it's still focusing on a Start Date section. Just click on start date section, the previous dates of selected date must be enable for selection.

Hello, thanks for your answer, I understood that it is a fine behaviour but I have task when I want to reverse start and end dates if start more than end.
If I focus on start input after start date selection I cant choose the end date
